# Primes of the form $\frac{p^2+5}{6}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

If $p$ is a prime greater than $3$, then $q=\frac{p^2+5}{6}$ is an integer. If $q$ is prime too, we have $\;q\equiv1\mod4$. The first primes so obtained (smaller than $10000$) are:
$$5, 29, 61, 89, 229, 281, 1321, 2129, 2689, 2861, 3221, 3701, 4649, 6469, 8741, 9049, 9521$$
Apart from the first ($5$), all such primes can be written as
$$q=25a^2+b^2\;\;\;\;(q\gt5)$$
Is there any simple modular arithmetic argument that can be used to prove this property?

Comment: Observe that $q\equiv 1\pmod{4}$. Therefore, it is a sum of squares. Now, the remainders of squares modulo $5$ are $0,1,4$. $q$ is both a sum of squares and a square itself, modulo $5$.  If we were not allowed to use $0$, then the sum of two $1$ gives remainder $2$, the sum of two $4$ gives remainder $3$, and the sum of a $1$ and $4$ gives remainder $0$, which can only happen for $q=5$.

Comment: Although $5$ is not of your chosen form, $29=25\cdot 1^2+2^2;\ 61=25\cdot 1^2+6^2;\ 89=25\cdot 1^2+8^2;\ 229=25\cdot 3^2+2^2$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, here is a nice argument:

Since $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ there exist some $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $q = x^2+y^2$. This is [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares).

Now, since $6q = p^2+5$ and $p>5$ we get that $q \equiv 1,4 (\text{mod } 5)$.

We want to prove that $5 \mid x$ or $5 \mid y$. Assume the contrary. Then $x^2, y^2 \equiv 1,4 \pmod 5$ and hence $x^2+y^2 \equiv 0,2,3 \pmod 5$, i.e. $q \equiv 0,2,3 \pmod 5$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: So this is true whether $p$ is prime or not, as long as $\gcd(p,6)=1$ and $p\neq 5.$