# Primes of the form $\frac{p^{2^k}+2}3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4188800/primes-of-the-form-fracp256) I asked to prove that the primes of the form $\,q=\frac{p^2+5}{6}\,$ $(\gcd(p,6)=1)$ can be written as
$$q=(5\cdot a)^2+b^2$$
The question was positively answered by [cos-dm-math21](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/679837/cos-dm-math21) and [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews).
I think that with similar arguments one could prove that:
$$q=\frac{p^4+5}{6}=(20\cdot a)^2+b^2$$
Moreover, if $\,\gcd(p,3)=1$, $\,k\in N\,$ and
$$q=\frac{p^{2^k}+2}3$$ is prime, then
$$q=(a\cdot2^{k+1})^2+b^2$$
Is it possible to prove rigorously the last statement?